# How to define an unwrapped response in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi

I have this component:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    book:
      type: object
      required:
       - id
      properties:
        id:
         type: string
        title:
         type: string
        author:
         type: string
```

Is there a way to define a response object that includes the book attributes using this component? The response is this:

```json
{
  "id": "xxxxx",
  "title": "This is title",
  "author": "John"
}
```

I tried like this:

```yaml
responses:
  200-response:
    description: HTTP 200 response
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            book:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/book'
```

but it has the parent object of book instead of the attributes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just put the schema `$ref` directly under `schema`.

```yaml
responses:
  200-response:
    description: HTTP 200 response
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/book'
```